# Merging Files that are partially matched in name in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge

I am in a situation where I have a large number of files. I need to merge these files based on matching parts of their names. I have to merge any one of the 5 files that include the name: Streptococcus_salivarius and any one of the 10 files that include the name Streptococcus_thermophilus for every ATGC008.COGXXXX number, and then generate a new file from these mergers. The directory containing the files and their naming scheme looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA5DP.jpg) and an individual file will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97YCz.jpg).

I can quite easily convert the files into .fasta format if any solution requires it.

I initially went with a more manual approach to combining files in python, copying and pasting their names into the script but with 872 combinations needed to be done this soon turned incredibly menial. As such I tried to automate the process by drawing directly from the directory containing the file and produced this:

```
import os
os.chdir("F:\PostGrad_Research\Programming_Files\Dumped_Files\Phylip_OG")
strainsToMerge = ['Streptococcus_thermophilus', 'Streptococcus_salivarius']
              #a list fo the strains that you want to access
for cogNumber in range(maxCogNumber):
    for i in range(2):
            filename = open('ATGC008.COG'+str(cogNumber)+ '.phy','w') #construct the filename to access the file
    infile = open(filename,'r')          #open the file
    sequences = infile.read()            #read the file
    subSequences = re.split('\w+',sequences)     #split the file with the header
    firstSequence[i] = subSequences[i].strip()   #extract the first sequence and make sure you've got rid of the whitespace at the start and end
    firstSequence[i] = re.sub('[\r\n]','',firstSequence[i])

outfile = open('ATGC008.COG'+str(cogNumber)+ '.phy','w')
    outfile.write('2 '+str(len(firstSequence[0])+'\n'))
    for i in range(2):
            outfile.write(firstSequence[i]+'\n'))
    outfile.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\PostGrad_Research\Programming_Files\Merge_Fasta.py", line 8, in <module>
for cogNumber in range(max.cogNumber):
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'cogNumber'
```

Any and all help/ advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to mention cogNumber in quotes. Like str('cogNumber'). Otherwise python treats it as a variable.

Comment: outfile.write(firstSequence[i]+'\n')) ---> kindly correct this also, extra closing parenthesis

Comment: @DiwakarSHARMA, thanks for pointing this mistake out, I'm a bit embarrassed indeed.

Comment: Hello @Joshua, I appreciate your looking at this for me. I've done as you suggested and now have the error: NameError: name 'maxcogNumber' is not defined, do you have any further ideas? Thanks –

Comment: @James you mentioned 'maxcogNumber' in for loop but it seems you did not assign a value for it.

Comment: @Joshua yes indeed, my mistake, I've set it to 1092, as that's the highest number my files go to (Gene ID 1092) now it's reading the first digit in the file, but not the other three, for example: 0001 is being read as 0, is there anyway I can specify that cogNumber is a 4 digit number?

Comment: @James problem with the 'cogNumber' is it will start from 0 , 1 and so on upto the range of maxcogNumber. So you appending this value at the end of your filename. If you want to start it from 1 then you need to mention in the range like 'range(1,maxCogNumber+1)'

Comment: so if you want to append a four digit number just use if else like this:                           if cogNumber<10:

Comment: consider to give upvote

Comment: @Joshua Just wanted to let you know I have upvoted the answer, but my reputation is too low for it to be seen as I'm still very new to stackoverflow

Comment: appreciated @James. I believe your  doubt was cleared .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   import os
    os.chdir("F:\PostGrad_Research\Programming_Files\Dumped_Files\Phylip_OG")
    strainsToMerge = ['Streptococcus_thermophilus', 'Streptococcus_salivarius']
                  #a list fo the strains that you want to access
    maxCogNumber=1092
    for cogNumber in range(1,maxCogNumber+1):
        a=''
        if 1<=cogNumber<10:
            a='000'+str(cogNumber)
        elif 10<=cogNumber<100:
            a='00'+str(cogNumber)
        elif 100<=cogNumber<1000:
            a='0'+str(cogNumber)
        else:
            a=str(cogNumber)
        for i in range(2):
                filename = open('ATGC008.COG'+a+ '.phy','w') #construct the filename to access the file
        infile = open(filename,'r')          #open the file
        sequences = infile.read()            #read the file
        subSequences = re.split('\w+',sequences)     #split the file with the header
        firstSequence[i] = subSequences[i].strip()   #extract the first sequence and make sure you've got rid of the whitespace at the start and end
        firstSequence[i] = re.sub('[\r\n]','',firstSequence[i])

    outfile = open('ATGC008.COG'+a+ '.phy','w')
        outfile.write('2 '+str(len(firstSequence[0])+'\n'))
        for i in range(2):
                outfile.write(firstSequence[i]+'\n'))
        outfile.close()
```